# How to test GraphQLError exception in graphene_django or graphql_jwt?

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django, django-graphql-jwt

I am implementing user types and authentication in django using graphene_django and graphql_jwt. Here are my two files: the code and the corresponding tests located in a folder named 'users' which is app-level folder(but not a django app)

**schema.py**

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType, id=graphene.Int(required=True))
    me = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def resolve_user(self, info, id):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=id)
        return user

    def resolve_me(self, info):
        current_user = info.context.user
        if current_user.is_anonymous:
            raise GraphQLError("Not logged in !")
        return current_user
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphql import GraphQLError
from graphql.error.located_error import GraphQLLocatedError
from graphql_jwt.testcases import JSONWebTokenTestCase

class TestUserAuthentication(JSONWebTokenTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username='Moctar', password='moctar')

    # @unittest.skip("Cannot handle raised GraphQLError")
    def test_not_autenticated_me(self):
        query = '''
        {
            me{
                id
                username
                password
            }
        }
        '''
        with self.assertRaises(GraphQLError, msg='Not logged in !'):
            self.client.execute(query)

    def test_autenticated_me(self):
        self.client.authenticate(self.user)
        query = '''
        {
            me{
                id 
                username
                password
            }
        }
        '''
        self.client.execute(query)
```

Then when i run my tests through `python manage.py test users` it says this:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_not_autenticated_me (tests.TestUserAuthentication)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_username/my_projects/server/arjangen/app/users/tests.py", line 97, in test_not_autenticated_me
    self.client.execute(query)
AssertionError: GraphQLError not raised : Not logged in !

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.531s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I have searched stackoverflow like this one 
[Exception raised but not caught by assertRaises
][1]

[1]: [Exception raised but not caught by assertRaises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679966/exception-raised-but-not-caught-by-assertraises) but this can still not solve my issue. So how does GraphQLError really can be tested ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line on `test_not_autenticated_me()`:

```
self.client.authenticate(self.user)
```

Because what `authenticate()` does is to login and get JWT token.
If you don't login, the default user wiil be AnonymousUser object.

Comment: Actually that line was a mistake in the question. it's by removing that line that my error above appears. Thanks for pinpointing the mistake!